# shell script to convert numbers to asterisk

Tags: shell

I have a variable that holds a number, using a shell script how can I convert the number to asterisk characters, for example 5 would be converted to `*****` , 2 would be converted to `**`

Comment: You mean you want to map every number to a special character?

Comment: sorry, I did not see that my question did not include the asterisk characters,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On simple solution is to use perl:

```
VAR=5
perl -e "print '*' x $VAR"
```

other solution is to use `seq`:

```
VAR=5
for i in `seq $VAR` ; do echo -n '*' ; done
```

Comment: Python variant: `python -c 'print "*" *'$VAR`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
$ echo "azerty5qwerty5" | perl -pe 's/5/sprintf "%s", "," x $&/ge'
azerty,,,,,qwerty,,,,,
```